# Need help within a loop to group data

Tags: php

Need some help, been going around this for ages, but just cant seem to solve it. I've got some data in a field called "Term Year PrNo". The data in this field is like below:

```
[2010-201110]Winter - 2010 - 1st 
[2010-201111]Winter - 2010 - 2nd 
[2010-201120]Spring - 2011 - 1st 
[2010-201121]Spring - 2011 - 2nd 
[2010-201130]Summer - 2011 - 1st 
[2010-201131]Summer - 2011 - 2nd
[2011-201210]Winter - 2011 - 1st 
[2011-201211]Winter - 2011 - 2nd 
[2011-201220]Spring - 2012 - 1st 
[2011-201221]Spring - 2012 - 2nd 
[2011-201230]Summer - 2012 - 1st 
[2011-201231]Summer - 2012 - 2nd 
[2012-201310]Winter - 2012 - 1st 
[2012-201311]Winter - 2012 - 2nd 
[2012-201320]Spring - 2013 - 1st 
[2012-201321]Spring - 2013 - 2nd 
[2012-201330]Summer - 2013 - 1st
```

I need to make each row of data in that field a radio button selection, which I've managed to do by sticking the contents of the field and spitting it out as an input field. I've also used regex to clean the look of the input value - i.e. remove the first sort field. So far so good. The problem I cant seem to solve is I need to break the data down in segments and wrap them around a div class called yearblock based on the years, 2010-2011 | 2011-2012 | 2012-2013, so that I can arrange them nicely using CSS. I've managed to figure out how to start div class, by comparing previous year to current year, but I cant seem to figure out how to appropriately put the end  in after echoing out my input. Hope this makes sense, can someone look at my code and point me in the right direction please?

```
<?php
$arrayTermdates = array();

foreach($termsResult->getRecords() as $key => $term)
{
    $arrayTermdates[] = $term->getField('Term Year PrNo');
}

$arrayTermdates = array_unique($arrayTermdates);

sort($arrayTermdates, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

foreach($arrayTermdates as $termdate) 
{   
    preg_match_all("/\[[^)]+\]/",$termdate,$matches);

    $year = str_replace('[', '', $matches[0][0]);
    $year = str_replace(']', '', $year);            
    $year = str_replace(' ', '', substr($year, 0, -2));  

    $termdate = preg_replace("/\[[^)]+\]/","",$termdate);                   

    /*
    /  - opening delimiter (necessary for regular expressions, can be any character that doesn't appear in the regular expression
    \[ - Match an opening parenthesis
    [^)]+ - Match 1 or more character that is not a closing parenthesis
    \] - Match a closing parenthesis
    /  - Closing delimiter
    */

    if ($previousYear != $year || $previousYear == '') 
        {
            echo '<div class="yearblock">';
            echo '<strong>'.$year.'</strong><br />';                        
        }

?>

    <div class="term_value_list">
    <input name="Termdate[]" type="radio" value="<?php echo $termdate; ?>">
<?php       

    $TermdatesArray = explode('-',$termdate);

    $Termdisplay = $TermdatesArray[0].' '.$TermdatesArray[1].' ['.str_replace(' ', '', $TermdatesArray[2]).' PR]';              

    echo $Termdisplay;

?>

<!-- I need to echo an </div> for div class yearblock -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. I'm going to make a little simplification to your code to get rid of the regexp, however.

First off, we are going to initiate a year tracker. This will allow us to keep track of which year we are in.

```
 $myCurrentYear = false;
```

From there, we'll loop through your rows. The first check we will do is to check if the year is different. If it is, and the current year was not false, we'll output a `</div>`. Then, if it was different, we'll print headers for the new year.

```
 foreach ($arrayTermdates as $date) {
     $newdate = split("-",substr($date,strpos($date,"]")+1));
     // Gotta remember to trim stuff
     $year = (int)trim($newdate[1]);
     if ($year != $myCurrentYear) {
        if ($myCurrentYear !== false) {
           echo "</div>";
        }
        $myCurrentYear = $year;
        echo "<div class='yearblock'><strong>Year ".$myCurrentYear."-".($myCurrentYear+1)."</strong>:";
     }
     // Do your processing here
 }
 // NOTE: the last one won't be closed. We'll close it here
 if ($myCurrentYear !== false) {
     echo "</div>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your first div before the first output:

```
echo '<div class="yearblock">';
```

Then close the block and open a new one each time your `if()` condition is true:

```
if ($previousYear != $year || $previousYear == '') 
{
    echo '</div><div class="yearblock">';
    echo '<strong>'.$year.'</strong><br />';                        
}
```

And finally, close the final div after you have finished creating output:

```
echo '</div>';
```